# ext.net gridview horizontal scrollbar not visible

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ext.net

i'm generating `EXT.NET` gridview dynamically as below,

```
public GridPanel GetGridView()
    {
        return new GridPanel
        {
            Border = false,
            ID = "grd",
            Cls = "x-grid-custom",
            StyleSpec = "margin-top:7px; margin-left:-2px",
            Scroll = ScrollMode.Both,
            OverflowX = Overflow.Auto,
            EnableColumnHide = false,
            ColumnLines = true,
            ForceFit = false,
          //Width = 1100,
            EmptyText = "No rows to display",
            Store = { this.CreateTabularStore() },
            ColumnModel =
            {
                Columns = {
                             // columns list 
                    }
            },
            Features = {
                           new Grouping(){HideGroupedHeader=false }
                           },
            View = { new Ext.Net.GridView() { LoadMask = true, LoadingText = "Loading..." } }
        };
    }
```

i'm getting this grid inside my action method and adding this to a `Container()`

but the rendered grid is not showing the scrollbars, especially the horizontal one,

i tried with adding fixed width to each column as well as to the grid.

Comment: try adding overflow: auto to the css on the grid

Comment: @MattBodily: added `OverflowX = Overflow.Auto` still no result

Comment: this should render as a table.  Look at the css on whatever the container is and make sure there is overflow: auto; in it.

Comment: @user3085995, if you update the original post with a runnable and simplified sample, I would investigate it.

Comment: Thank you, but I expect something to copy, paste and run without any changes. Please read [this guide](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?3440).